# Remove duplicates from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dml

I'm a SQL newbie and this is my first question posted. I need your expert advice please. Forgive me if the format is not correct or if this question has already been shot in the past but I couldn't find the solution.

I have one table called DEPOSITORS with more than 4500 records. Some of account_number in the account_number field are duplicates but with different DEPS amount. In order to obtain the TOT_DEPS amount by account_number I run the following SELECT statement:

```
select account_number,deps,sum(deps) over(partition by account_number) as Tot_Deps from depositors
order by account_number 

+-------------------+----------+------------+
| ACCOUNT_NUMBER    |    DEPS  |  TOT_DEPS  |
+-------------------+----------+------------+
| Account_number1   |    50.00 |    90.00   |
| Account_number1   |    40.00 |    90.00   |
| Account_number2   |    50.00 |    50.00   |
| Account_number3   |    40.00 |    70.00   |
| Account_number3   |    30.00 |    70.00   |
+-------------------+----------+------------+
```

What I need to do but I'm stuck is to remove the account_number duplicates as I have already found the total of both records. Thanks

Comment: you want to delete duplicate account number no matter what DEPS amount ? or remove  duplicate account number and DEPS ??

Comment: duplicate account number and DEPS but not the tot_deps

Answer (score 1):

You just need an aggregation:

```
select account_number, sum(deps) as Tot_Deps
from depositors
group by account_number
order by account_number ;
```

Comment: either you do sum(deps) or add it to group by :)

Comment: @Al-3sli . . . The OP wants the sum by account.  The `deps` field should not have been there.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I created another similar table and added the above  aggregation and it worked. Was easier than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

use this to delete duplicate record :

```
DELETE depositors
FROM depositors
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT MIN(RowId) as RowId, account_number, deps 
FROM depositors
GROUP BY account_number, deps
) as KeepRows ON
depositors.RowId = KeepRows.RowId
WHERE
KeepRows.RowId IS NULL
```

Comment: Just to let you know that I've managed to retrieve the results needed using both sql and excel. On the other hand the above query is not clear to me, I didn't understand the logic behind. If you have time could you please shed some lights. Anyway I really appreciated your prompt and helpful replies.Thanks

Comment: Nice that you find what you seek, this to query used to **delete** duplicate rows **(account_number, deps)** From your table and keep only unique rows.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need the following batch:

```
select ACCOUNT_NUMBER, SUM(DEPS) DEPS into #t1 from DEPOSITORS group by ACCOUNT_NUMBER
delete from DEPOSITORS
insert into DEPOSITORS select * from #t1
drop table #t1
go
select * from DEPOSITORS
```